# Active Records Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I will go stright to the point:

I have these two models:

- `User`
- `Followed`

The `Followed` model has

- `user_id` (the user that follows another user) and
- `followed_id`, the user that is followed by the user with `user_id`.

the `User` model looks like this:

```rb
has_many :followeds, foreign_key: :followed_id, dependent: :destroy
```

the `Followed` model looks like this

```rb
belongs_to :user
```

What I want to achieve is this: I want to retrieve the followers for the `current_user` (the logged in user).

I have some idea on what I should do, which is something like this:

1 - join `users` table with `followeds` table

2 - select users where `users.id = followeds.user_id` (the user who follows the `current_user`)

3 - and (condition) `followeds.followed_id = current_user.id` (the user who is followed is the `current_user`, the one logged in)

I don' t know if it can help, but the following query is the one that I succesfully used (with the kind help of stack overflow users) to retrive the users that a user follows:

```rb
@users = User.joins(:followeds).where(followeds: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

Based on that I believe that the query should look something like

```rb
@users = User.joins(:followeds).where(followeds: {followed_id: current_user.id})
```

and then some  query to select `users.id = followeds.user_id`

Comment: Thank you,  but I am sorry, I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I clear understand your associations

```
User.where(id: Followed.select(:user_id).where(followed_id: current_user.id))
```

It will generate something like this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT user_id FROM followeds
  WHERE followed_id = <current_user_id>
);
```

You can also add association to `User` model with [`:source`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-source) and [`:through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-through) options

```
has_many :followers, through: :followeds, source: :user
```

And than just

```
current_user.followers
```

This will generate query like this

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN followeds ON users.id = followeds.user_id
WHERE followeds.followed_id = <current_user_id>;
```

Comment: Yes. It does work Thank you very much. It seems that  I cannot upvote your answer because I have just started posting.  I really appreciate it. I have marked it at solved.

Comment: I have upvoted it now! Thanks again!